# Erro de tipo no retorno de uma função derivativa

Tags: c, matemática

Tenho o seguinte código em C, estou compilando ele no linux usando gcc e -lm (segue abaixo)

O que acontece é o seguinte: f(x+dx) - f(x) dá zero ( o que não é! ) As funções f(x+dx) e f(x) estão sendo calculadas certo, até havia colocado um print para ver e a diferença dela não excede o a precisão disponível (ex. dx muito pequeno e f(x+dx)-f(x) = 0.0 ).

Gostaria de entender o que está acontecendo! 
Tentei usar 2.0 (para não ser um 'inteiro'), tentei colocar os valores em variáveis e passar as variáveis (não direto no return ou calcular a função na hora de dar o print), e várias outras coisas. O que estou fazendo errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x){
    double r=0;
    /**/
    printf("\n x= %f, f(x) = %f\n",x, pow(x,2)+6*x);
    /**/
    r = pow(x,2)+6*x;
    return r;
}
double derivatef(double x, double){
    return (( f(x+dx) - f(x) ) / dx);
}
void main(){
    double f_x, df_x; //d = derivada;
    /*
    1- Usando o método da derivada à direita,
    calcule f'(x) nos pontos x=-2 e 2.
    Como você sabe se o valor encontrado é
    correto sem calcular o valor analítico de f'(x) ?
    */
    f_x = f(2);
    df_x = derivatef(2, 0.001);
    printf("x=2, f(x) = %f, f'(x) = %f", f_x, df_x);
}
```

Comment: Esse código tem vários erros de sintaxe e nem compila.

Comment: Eu consegui compilar e não houve nenhum erro de sintaxe. O que achei estranho é que estava recebendo zero como resultado da subtração. O que errei foi o na hora de declarar a função (não usei o double antes para definir o tipo dela.) Meu professor me respondeu por email isso agora. Até quis apagar a pergunta mas não achei onde.

Comment: Então seu compilador é maluco. http://ideone.com/pVLKM3

Comment: Provavelmente o que me fez ficar mais tempo tentando consertar o erro. Não defini o tipo por vício de programar em outra linguagem. Estava procurando outro erro pois esse tipo de declaração era natural para mim. Obrigado.

Comment: @AlecksRolf: perdesta alguns caracteres na definição da funcão derivada: `double dx){`

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema é relacionado a sintaxe do seu código.

Em **C**, a declaração do tipo do método é muito importante, como seus métodos `f` e `derivatef` não tem um tipo definido, o compilador define o retorno do método como `int`.

Os tipos `char`, `int` e `void *`, tem um tratamento diferente de `float` e `double`, como o C é convertido para **Assembly**, se não houver a especificação correta dos tipos, não é feito o tratamento do valor.

Altere seus métodos para:

```
double f(double x){
    double r=0.;
    /**/
    printf("\n x= %f, f(x) = %f\n",x, pow(x,2)+6*x);
    /**/
    r = pow(x,2)+6*x;
    return r;
}
double derivatef(double x, double dx){
    return (( f(x+dx) - f(x) ) / dx);
}
```

> A declaração do tipo de retorno é essencial na programação, não a fazer pode acarretar em alguns problemas em seu sistema. **Nunca declare um método com retorno sem especificar o seu tipo de retorno**.